# How to position a div under a link on click?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to do something like this very site does when you hover over a users image in the answers. Since I've never much worked with CSS, I've no idea how to get this right. I've been given the CSS and design. The data will be loaded server side and sent to the page using jQuery.

My problem is, a link can be anywhere on the page but will all appear below each other with slight differences in margin from the left. The div needs to be just under that always. How can I do this?

This is the entire CSS I'm working with. You can copy and paste it. Anything is changeable now. It's the positioning part that has me stuck.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Title Less</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.prod-info').click(function() {
        var data = 'id=5705';
        if(data) {
            $.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                url:"/products/info/",
                data:data,
                dataType:'json',
                beforeSend:function(x){

                },
                success: function(x){

                },
                error: function(x){

                },
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
#prod-menu {
    -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
    -moz-border-image: none;
    -moz-border-left-colors: none;
    -moz-border-right-colors: none;
    -moz-border-top-colors: none;
    background-color: #505050;
    border-color: #444444 #1C1C1C #1C1C1C;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    border-right: 1px solid #1C1C1C;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 0 1px 0 #727272 inset;
    color: #E3E3E3;
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 1.2;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    width: 300px;
    z-index: 320;

}
#prod-menu .pm-gravatar {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 8px;
}
#prod-menu .pm-header-info .pm-prod-link, #prod-menu .pm-header-info .mod-flair {
    color: #E2E2E2 !important;
    font-size: 18px;
}
#prod-menu .pm-header-info .pm-flair .badgecount, #prod-menu .pm-header-info .pm-flair .reputation-score {
    color: #E2E2E2;
}
#prod-menu .pm-about-me {
    clear: both;
    font-size: 11px;
    margin: 5px 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#prod-menu .pm-links a {
    font-size: 11px;
    margin-right: 8px;
}
#prod-menu a, #prod-menu a:visited {
    color: #B4D4EC;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#prod-menu a:hover {
    color: #DCECF7;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">

<div class="prod-info">I am Link A</div>
<div class="prod-info" style="margin-top:150px;margin-left:100px">I am Link B</div>
<div class="prod-info" style="margin-top:300px;margin-left:200px">I am Link C</div>

<div id="prod-menu">
I am the product info div!
</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you give us an image of what you want? I'm a little confused
http://jsfiddle.net/VkaFv/

Comment: Don't have time to write something atm, but [the click event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/click) on mdn, [jQuery's offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) and [jQuery's width()](http://api.jquery.com/width/) and [jQuery's height()](http://api.jquery.com/height/) are what you need.

Comment: @romain It's the same as how you hover over a users avatar on this page and his profile loads in a tiny div. I'm stuck with how to get the div below each link, when each link appears at diff locations on the page. Copy and paste my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add this statments :

```
$('.prod-info').mouseenter(function () {
    currTop = $(this).offset().top+20;
    currLeft = $(this).offset().left;
    $('#prod-menu').css({
        top: currTop + "px",
        left: currLeft + "px",
        display: "block"
    })
});
$('.prod-info').mouseleave(function () {
    currTop = $(this).offset().top;
    currLeft = $(this).offset().left;
    $('#prod-menu').css({
        display: "none"
    })
});
```

And i also replace `position:relative` by `position:absolute`.

Hope this help.

Check the [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bDtbZ/6/)

Comment: Works nice. I'll take it from here. I've updated your fiddle. You've misspelled mouseleave and mouseenter and mouseleave are the same :-)

Comment: Opps yep sorry for the mistake

Comment: Why does it flicker so badly on mouseleave?

Comment: I added 20px on currTop during the edit. check the fiddle. Is it better for you ?

Comment: Wow! It's beautiful now :-) Vive la France!